# if Statement to Override Value

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, statistics

I'm trying to implement this formula from a paper *(ref)*:

[image]

I tried:

```
import statsmodels.api

n = 1 # samples
x = 1 # positive results

# Range of significance
Min=0
Max=1
Step=.01
Alpha = np.arange(Min,Max+Step,Step)

Low  = []
High = []

for  A in Alpha:
  low, high = statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint(x, n, alpha=A, method='jeffreys')
  if x == 0: low  == 0 # these lines
  if x == n: high == 1 # aren't working
  Low.append(low)
  High.append(high)
```

But that gives me this:

[image]

My **if** statements are supposed to override the values of **low** and **high** when **x=0** or **x=n**. How can I get them to work please?

*ref: Brown, L.D., Cai, T.T. and DasGupta, A., 2001. Interval estimation for a binomial proportion. Statistical science, pp.101-117.*

Comment: Stats question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465609/confidence-intervals-of-the-positive-predictive-value-adjusting-my-bootstrap/469033

Comment: change your if clauses `low == 0` and `high == 1` to `low = 0` and `high = 1`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @jfaccioni for the answer; that I just want the one = like this

```
import statsmodels.api

n = 1 # samples
x = 1 # positive results

# Range of significance
Min=0
Max=1
Step=.01
Alpha = np.arange(Min,Max+Step,Step)

Low  = []
High = []

for  A in Alpha:
  low, high = statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportion_confint(x, n, alpha=A, method='jeffreys')
  if x == 0: low  = 0
  if x == n: high = 1
  Low.append(low)
  High.append(high)
```